# Adding .o files path to ld default (crtbeginS.o, not .so files)

Tags: gcc, g++, ld, binutils

When using GCC to compile most things, I get this error:

```
/..//bin/ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
```

crtbeginS.o exists at /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/6.0.0/crtbeginS.o (Installed from GCC trunk, 6.0.0-trunk)

I added that directory to ldconfig and ran ldconfig, but it didn't pick up any additional directories.  (I'm thinking since it's a .o rather than .so)

As a temporary fix, I tried making a symlink to /usr/local/lib64/crtbeginS.o - but that gives the same error.

What can I do, so the /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/6.0.0/ directory is always looked at to find the library?

If I run `gcc -print-search-dirs|grep "/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/6.0.0"`, it shows libraries: =/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/6.0.0/:...  But, this is of course gcc not ld.

If I run `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR`, I see /usr/local/lib/gcc_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/6.0.0 is NOT included.

I'd really like to do this as a system-wide default, so I don't have to give -L to everything.  I'm fine building bintools from source, if that's necessary.

Answer (score -1):

> What can I do, so the
> /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/6.0.0/ directory is always
> looked at to find the library?

You have to change the ***ld configuration***.

Depending on your system, ld.so is configurable with a file in /etc/, and possibly with files under '/etc/ld.so.conf.d or /etc/ld.so.d. The manual pages for [ld.so](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) and [ldconfig](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html) are a good place to start reading on how to change the configuration for **ld**.